# Java backend and C# frontend how does it work?

Tags: c#, java, web-services

So I'd like to connect a wpf c# client to a java backend via web services.
I have a few questions regarding this and I am a bit new to web services so please bear with me..

1. Would I be using a wcf web service or would it most likely be a java construct (and if so which one?)
2. Would I be using soap or rest? i know this is a big topic but I'm just looking for which one would most likely be used.
3. Lastly, would I be able to run java methods via my c#? for example say I have a method that lives on the server called called "Customer GetCustomer(int id);" ... would i be able to call this method in my c# client? And how would the customer come back would it come back as xml and then I'd have to parse this xml and build a Customer object on the client side? meaning, would I have a duplicated class definition on both the server and client, or would I somehow share the same Customer reference?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Expose a SOAP service from your Java backend, and access it using WCF. Easy and painless
2. SOAP is easier, and requires less work when you use WCF.
3. Yes. SOAP allows you to define ComplexTypes which would represent your classes, so the C# mappings would be pretty much the same as your Java ones.

I would recommend reading up about SOAP and WebServices in general, that should answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: Notice that a tool like enunciate (http://enunciate.codehaus.org/) could allow one to easily obtain client stubs from server code without having to worry about intermediate layers.

Comment: Does that mean that my java server would be somehow hosted in iis if i am using wcf or how does it work?

Comment: No, you would need a JEE Service Container for that, like Apache Tomcat. But if your Java backend isn't already designed as a webservice, what exactly are you trying to do then?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding question number 3, when you expose your logic in Java as as a web service... Now I do not have enough knowlegde on how to deploy a java web service but when you deploy it, what remains is to create a proxy in C# and start calling your web methods.

---

**Elaboration:**
Creating a proxy (in .NET web services or WCF) (AKA adding a Web/Service reference) means that you recreate all the exposed classes/types in your java WS methods as local types in C#. These types will be exposed (on Java WS side) using an XML document called WSDL (Web Service Definition Language). This will make a second copy of all the types used in the Java WS webmethods in your C# program, you can call this redundent, but this is the only way that you can communicate with a Java WS from .NET

Afterwards, when your C# program runs, and reaches the call to the proxy of your Java WebMethod, the proxy will transform the web method call's arguments (class instances) used by the WS proxy to XML representation. This is called encoding your object(s) using SOAP, the client creates a SOAP envelope that contains all the necessary data/objects - arguments (encoded with SOAP) and sends the SOAP envelope to the JAVA WS. The Java WS decodes (reverses XML to java instances) the objects embedded in the envelope, and calls the correct Web Method according to some hints also found in the SOAP envelope.

When the call to the Java WS is completed all the instances that must be returned to the client (if any) are also encoded using SOAP, and sent to the client as a response to the WS call.